# Laptop as wireless access point

Tags: wireless, networking, wireless-access-point

I have a VAIO Laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit). I use a wired internet connection. I want to share this connection using my laptop's wifi as access point. How can i do this?

Comment: you can't. Because laptop provide wireless receiver, not transmitter. To send wireless signal you need a transmitter or transceiver. So need a wireless router for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the networking icon in the top right hand corner,and choose the Create New Wireless Network option.  Enter a name for your network, choose the security you require and set up a security key (if security is enabled).  Hit Create and your wireless network will be create and begin broadcasting.

This process depends on your card supporting the ad-hoc connection mode.